# How do i move the "interaction" with the "blob" in this animated blob?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I downloaded this javascript blob graphic, I've added it to my page, and moved it to the right using CSS, But when I move the mouse to interact with the blob, it still thinks the blob is in the middle of the screen. How do I move the interaction to the right with the blob?

```js
let canvas, ctx;
let render, init;
let blob;

class Blob {
  constructor() {
    this.points = [];
  }

  init() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.numPoints; i++) {
      let point = new Point(this.divisional * (i + 1), this);
      // point.acceleration = -1 + Math.random() * 2;
      this.push(point);
    }
  }

  render() {
    let canvas = this.canvas;
    let ctx = this.ctx;
    let position = this.position;
    let pointsArray = this.points;
    let radius = this.radius;
    let points = this.numPoints;
    let divisional = this.divisional;
    let center = this.center;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    pointsArray[0].solveWith(pointsArray[points - 1], pointsArray[1]);

    let p0 = pointsArray[points - 1].position;
    let p1 = pointsArray[0].position;
    let _p2 = p1;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(center.x, center.y);
    ctx.moveTo((p0.x + p1.x) / 2, (p0.y + p1.y) / 2);

    for (let i = 1; i < points; i++) {

      pointsArray[i].solveWith(pointsArray[i - 1], pointsArray[i + 1] || pointsArray[0]);

      let p2 = pointsArray[i].position;
      var xc = (p1.x + p2.x) / 2;
      var yc = (p1.y + p2.y) / 2;
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p1.x, p1.y, xc, yc);
      // ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);

      ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
      // ctx.fillRect(p1.x-2.5, p1.y-2.5, 5, 5);

      p1 = p2;
    }

    var xc = (p1.x + _p2.x) / 2;
    var yc = (p1.y + _p2.y) / 2;
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p1.x, p1.y, xc, yc);
    // ctx.lineTo(_p2.x, _p2.y);

    // ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    // ctx.stroke();

    /*
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
        if(this.mousePos) {
          let angle = Math.atan2(this.mousePos.y, this.mousePos.x) + Math.PI;
          ctx.fillRect(center.x + Math.cos(angle) * this.radius, center.y + Math.sin(angle) * this.radius, 5, 5);
        }
    */
    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
  }

  push(item) {
    if (item instanceof Point) {
      this.points.push(item);
    }
  }

  set color(value) {
    this._color = value;
  }
  get color() {
    return this._color || '#000000';
  }

  set canvas(value) {
    if (value instanceof HTMLElement && value.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'canvas') {
      this._canvas = canvas;
      this.ctx = this._canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
  }
  get canvas() {
    return this._canvas;
  }

  set numPoints(value) {
    if (value > 2) {
      this._points = value;
    }
  }
  get numPoints() {
    return this._points || 32;
  }

  set radius(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      this._radius = value;
    }
  }
  get radius() {
    return this._radius || 150;
  }

  set position(value) {
    if (typeof value == 'object' && value.x && value.y) {
      this._position = value;
    }
  }
  get position() {
    return this._position || { x: 0.5, y: 0.5 };
  }

  get divisional() {
    return Math.PI * 2 / this.numPoints;
  }

  get center() {
    return { x: this.canvas.width * this.position.x, y: this.canvas.height * this.position.y };
  }

  set running(value) {
    this._running = value === true;
  }
  get running() {
    return this.running !== false;
  }}


class Point {
  constructor(azimuth, parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.azimuth = Math.PI - azimuth;
    this._components = {
      x: Math.cos(this.azimuth),
      y: Math.sin(this.azimuth) };


    this.acceleration = -0.3 + Math.random() * 0.6;
  }

  solveWith(leftPoint, rightPoint) {
    this.acceleration = (-0.3 * this.radialEffect + (leftPoint.radialEffect - this.radialEffect) + (rightPoint.radialEffect - this.radialEffect)) * this.elasticity - this.speed * this.friction;
  }

  set acceleration(value) {
    if (typeof value == 'number') {
      this._acceleration = value;
      this.speed += this._acceleration * 2;
    }
  }
  get acceleration() {
    return this._acceleration || 0;
  }

  set speed(value) {
    if (typeof value == 'number') {
      this._speed = value;
      this.radialEffect += this._speed * 5;
    }
  }
  get speed() {
    return this._speed || 0;
  }

  set radialEffect(value) {
    if (typeof value == 'number') {
      this._radialEffect = value;
    }
  }
  get radialEffect() {
    return this._radialEffect || 0;
  }

  get position() {
    return {
      x: this.parent.center.x + this.components.x * (this.parent.radius + this.radialEffect),
      y: this.parent.center.y + this.components.y * (this.parent.radius + this.radialEffect) };

  }

  get components() {
    return this._components;
  }

  set elasticity(value) {
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      this._elasticity = value;
    }
  }
  get elasticity() {
    return this._elasticity || 0.001;
  }
  set friction(value) {
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      this._friction = value;
    }
  }
  get friction() {
    return this._friction || 0.0085;
  }}


blob = new Blob();

init = function () {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.setAttribute('touch-action', 'none');

  

  let resize = function () {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  };
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
  resize();

  let oldMousePoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let hover = false;
  let mouseMove = function (e) {

    let pos = blob.center;
    let diff = { x: e.clientX - pos.x, y: e.clientY - pos.y };
    let dist = Math.sqrt(diff.x * diff.x + diff.y * diff.y);
    let angle = null;

    blob.mousePos = { x: pos.x - e.clientX, y: pos.y - e.clientY };

    if (dist < blob.radius && hover === false) {
      let vector = { x: e.clientX - pos.x, y: e.clientY - pos.y };
      angle = Math.atan2(vector.y, vector.x);
      hover = true;
      // blob.color = '#77FF00';
    } else if (dist > blob.radius && hover === true) {
      let vector = { x: e.clientX - pos.x, y: e.clientY - pos.y };
      angle = Math.atan2(vector.y, vector.x);
      hover = false;
      blob.color = null;
    }

    if (typeof angle == 'number') {

      let nearestPoint = null;
      let distanceFromPoint = 100;

      blob.points.forEach(point => {
        if (Math.abs(angle - point.azimuth) < distanceFromPoint) {
          // console.log(point.azimuth, angle, distanceFromPoint);
          nearestPoint = point;
          distanceFromPoint = Math.abs(angle - point.azimuth);
        }

      });

      if (nearestPoint) {
        let strength = { x: oldMousePoint.x - e.clientX, y: oldMousePoint.y - e.clientY };
        strength = Math.sqrt(strength.x * strength.x + strength.y * strength.y) * 10;
        if (strength > 100) strength = 100;
        nearestPoint.acceleration = strength / 100 * (hover ? -1 : 1);
      }
    }

    oldMousePoint.x = e.clientX;
    oldMousePoint.y = e.clientY;
  };
  // window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
  window.addEventListener('pointermove', mouseMove);

  blob.canvas = canvas;
  blob.init();
  blob.render();
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  init();
});
```

```css
canvas { 
    position: absolute;
    touch-action: none;
}
 #canvarse {
     padding-left: 800px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="canvarse">
         <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
          <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/pep/0.4.3/pep.js"></script>
<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="js/script.js"></script>
  </div>
```

If you run the code snippet, you can see that the blob still thinks its in the middle of the canvas when it's actually where its supposed to be on the right.

I'm struggling to see how I can move the interaction across with the blob?
Anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like it was pretty easy you just have to play with the position function in your JavaScript, First remove your CSS completely because it is unnecessary and find this particular line on your JavaScript and change the X axis position if you want to move the blob horizontally and Y axis if you want vertical movement

```
get position() {
            return this._position || { x: 0.8, y: 0.5 };
          }
```

by default it was x:0.5 which means center so I changed it to 0.8  slight movement towards right side. hope this helps

Comment: I marked you answer as correct, but now I'm having another problem, when i scroll down the screen, the interaction moves down the screen with the viewport, so if i scroll down, i can interact with the blob about 4 inches below the blob.